# How to get the same sized font when rotated?

Tags: android, html, css, font-size

I have a fairly simple problem about which a lot has been written, but I have not found the answer.

Basically I have a layout in two main `div` sections, one of which uses about a third of the viewport. I reorganise them when rotated so the smaller one is still at one end (and about the same size), and that's all good – I set the sizes and positions with `@media` queries and `vh` and `vw`.

Where the problem comes is that I want the **same size text** in the main `div` whichever way the device is oriented, but browsers have their own idea about font size. I have tried to scale the font with `vh` and `vmax` and `em` and `px` etc. to no avail.

One solution I tried was given in [Font-sizing issue when rotate from portrait to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423282/font-sizing-issue-when-rotate-from-portrait-to-landscape) but it does not solve it, even if I refresh the page after rotating.

[image]

This simple example and images show what I mean, with just a font size demo. A similar result is obtained if I base the size on `vmax` instead. I'm not using Javascript like this in my actual code, it's just to show some text with the screen size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body { font-size: 40px !important; }
</style>

<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.writeln("<BR>");
document.writeln("screen = ");
document.writeln(screen.width);
document.writeln(" x ");
document.writeln(screen.height);
document.writeln("<BR>");
</script>

</body></html>
```

I have some buttons in the smaller area and (curiously) have no trouble sizing the text on *them*.

How can I achieve the **same size font**, without having to second-guess what the (unknown) browser will do? Firefox on my desktop PC is consistent but Samsung and Chrome browsers on my phone are not. The screenshots are from the Samsung browser, Chrome has a similar result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your font size that's changing, it's the page zoom that's changing. To verify, introduce an image or a simple pixel-sized square to your page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body { font-size: 40px !important; }
</style>

<body>
<span style="display:inline-block;width:40px;height:40px;background:red"></span>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.writeln("<BR>");
document.writeln("screen = ");
document.writeln(screen.width);
document.writeln(" x ");
document.writeln(screen.height);
document.writeln("<BR>");
</script>

</body></html>
```

As for the solution, adding a [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) would be the easiest:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: Ah yes! I did originally have the viewport `meta` tag but somehow it got lost in the fiddling and late-night session without me noticing. That has solved it, thank you.